# Write-To-StdOut inside callbacks and functions

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell and it looks like I have trouble with it's concept of pipes. As I understand:

- `Write-Host` writes "on the console" but [can not be reused/ captured](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/) from other scripts
- `Write-Output` puts something into the pipe. If the content of the pipe isn't used elsewhere, it's dumped onto the console. A calling script can use the output.

In virtually all scripting languages I know you can write to the console from anywhere in a way it can be used from calling scripts and without affecting the return value of a function.

So:

- Whats the benefit of this? At the moment, it looks elegant by design but not really practical.
- How can I write to the script output from within a function without affecting it's return value (no, I can't use `[Write-Host][1]`)
- How can I write to the script output from within a callback/ event like in

  ```
  $ect = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $ps -Action { Write-Somewhere $EventArgs.Data } -EventName 'ErrorDataReceived'
  ```

Background: the script is called from a wrapper file, called from a wrapper file called from Jenkins. Write-Output is correctly logged but I can not use it everywhere. I want to avoid dumping text into a temp file and read it back at the end to conserve timing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, if you want details how Write-Output works (and is intended to work), see BenN's answer.

Neither Write-Output nor Write-Host is really working for me. But Powershell has more options for writing on screen and to output channels to offer. I opted to use [Write-Verbose](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-verbose?view=powershell-5.1). I am not in control of the calling script but luckily, the Verbose-channel is already merged to standard output.

If that's not the case, you need to merge debug-output into standard-output manually:

```
.\test_writing_to_debug_output.ps1 4>&1 > a_logfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

A helpful effect of the distinction between `Write-Host` and `Write-Output` is that you can insert logging (`Write-Host`) in your functions without messing up the values they actually return to their callers (`Write-Output`).

Speaking of returning to callers, simply letting a value come out of an expression or cmdlet invocation will pass it on as output. Therefore, `5` on a line by itself and `Write-Output 5` are equivalent. A somewhat tricky concept is that PowerShell scripts don't have return values in the same sense as most programming languages do. Returning a value with the `Return` keyword is indistinguishable from allowing the value out the output pipeline and then exiting the function. In other words, `5; break` is the same as `Return 5`. The script output (which may be multiple objects) *is* the return value.

Objects that come out of script blocks registered as event actions are automatically stashed in the `Output` property of the event's job object, which is what you get back from `Register-ObjectEvent` if you use `-Action` to provide a script block. Here is an example script that notes the current date and time every time a timer fires:

```
$timer = New-Object System.Timers.Timer
$timer.Interval = 2000
$myEvent = Register-ObjectEvent $timer -EventName 'Elapsed' -Action {Get-Date}
$timer.Start()
```

The `$myEvent` variable will receive the job object from `Register-ObjectEvent`. `$myEvent.Output` will be an ever-growing array of times, one from every run of `Get-Date` in the event handler. (There are [some automatically defined variables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent?view=powershell-5.1#optional-parameters) that may be useful in such handlers.) In your case, once whatever's done generating the callbacks finishes, you could output `$ect.Output` to pass the captured data on to the calling script.

Alternatively, if you don't want to deal with custom event handlers, you can leave off the script block and instead supply a source identifier that names the event subscription. We could replace the `$myEvent` line from the previous example with this:

```
Register-ObjectEvent $timer -EventName 'Elapsed' -SourceIdentifier 'MyEvent'
```

Now events go into the event queue, tagged with our source identifier. To retrieve them later, we use [`Get-Event`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-event?view=powershell-5.1):

```
Get-Event -SourceIdentifier 'MyEvent'
```

Comment: Makes sense to me but I can try this earliest next wendesday. I'll either post my own answer or accept your one. Nevertheless: +1, thank you